# Eclipse RCP: Open View/ Part programmatically in detached mode

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I can open a view or part using `EPartService` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319866/eclipse-rcp-open-view-programmatically-the-e4-way)).

This will bring up the part within the last part stack as a new tab.

How can I bring up the part in detached mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add another Window or Trimmed Window to your Application.e4xmi and put your part in that window in the usual way. Turn 'To Be Rendered' off on the window.

To show the window containing the part use the model service:

```java
@Inject
ModelService modelService;
@Inject
MApplication app;


MUIElement window = modelService.find("second window id", app);

window.setToBeRendered(true);
```